# Testcontainers - Do not start container automatically during instantiation

Tags: java, integration-testing, junit5, testcontainers

Let's assume I have the following container in my integration test (JUnit 5):

```
@Container
private static GenericContainer databaseContainer =
        new GenericContainer("oscarfonts/h2:latest")
                .withExposedPorts(H2_TCP_PORT, H2_WEB_PORT);
```

With this the container will start automatically. Is there a way to tell testcontainers not to start the container automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `@Container` annotation is just used to start the container before your tests and tears it down afterwards.

An alternative would be to instantiate the `databaseContainer` and later on `start()` it manually - [Manual Container Lifecycle Control](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/)